# Django Meta Class Access Outer Attribute

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, inner-classes

Folks,

I need to implement a form that may vary a little depending on a variable. My class that subclasses ModelForms looks like this

```
class ConstantVwModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  #couple attributes

  def __init__(self, hasData, *args, **kwargs): 

  class Meta:
    fields = ('xx', 'yy' ..)
```

I am looking for the very best way to access the variable `hasData` from the inner `class Meta`, it would be like

```
class ConstantVwModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  #couple attributes

  def __init__(self, hasData, *args, **kwargs): 

  class Meta:
    if hasData:
      fields = ('xx', 'yy', ..)
    else:
      fields = ('hh', ..)
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do that and there's no way to achieve this. You can delete field on the fly in your `__init__` function explicitly:

```
class ConstantVwModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #couple attributes
    def __init__(self, hasData, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasData:
            del self.fields['hh']
        else:
            del self.fields['xx']
            del self.fields['yy']

    class Meta:
        model = ConstantVwModel
```

Comment: Shang, the only problem is that I need to have my model variable in my ``class Meta``. If I keep my ``model = MyClass`` in ``Meta`` and set my fields in the way you said (inside ``__init__``), django auto-make my form with all fields showing, disregarding my ``self.fields['xx'] = forms.CharField()`` declaration

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer. I still think it's better not to edit `Meta` class in django form. I found another way that might make your form dynamic without too much pain.

Comment: Cool, but then I am not able to set a field as hidden, right? Since I am deleting it from my form

Comment: "Field as hidden" and "remove fields from form" are 2 different things. If you make it hidden it's only hiding from the template. You can use either way, but if you only hide the fields, people can manipulate html or `POST` data somehow to post unauthorized data to the form, which might cause issues.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this difference. What I meant was, if I can only delete the field on the fly, would I be able to set one field's property on the fly? I.e. set it as hidden in my ``__init__``?

Comment: Yea, in `__init__` you can do `form.fields['xx'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())` to make the field hidden.